# Raw Data Decoding

Tags: java, encoding, raw-data

I have a coloumn in oracle DB of RAW type. 
I want to decode the values in them to understand what is there in it. 
Can I do this using java.
Please help.
One of the sample values in that coloumn is as follows.

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

Answer (score 0):

This seems to a gzip archive. Convert the hex values to bytes, store it in a file, and run gunzip on that.

Comment: How did you conclude `This seems to a gzip archive` ?

Comment: Many binary files start with some kind of magic number indicating the file type. I googled for the first 3 bytes: 1F8B08.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.. Can u just elaborate what i need to do step by step.